# Can I pull commits into a production system that has its own local commits?

Tags: git

I have a test and a production system which both have the same remote Git origin. Normally I would work on the test system, commit changes, push them to the remote origin and then pull them on the Production side. For some reason, some changes were done directly on the Production system. So on the production system, I now have to commit these changes (otherwise they would be unstaged changes and I would not be able to pull).

Can I pull from the remote repository into the the production system, even if the live system now has its own couple of commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what final result you want.

## production system = test system

in this case you could just "put aside" your changes on production and then pull in the changes that were pushed:

```
git stash # put the uncommitted changes aside in a stash
git pull # pull in the changes from the remote branch
```

## production system = test system + new changes

```
git stash # put the uncommitted changes aside
git pull # pull in the changes from the remote branch
git stash pop # apply the changes again. This might results in some conflicts which you'll have to resolve.
git commit # now you can cleanly commit these new changes
git push # and best push them back upstream so you can pull them on your test site.
```

Comment: upvoted because yes the changes that were made on the live system should also be available to the test system.

Comment: I tried it within a "prototype" project and commited the changes on the production system locally, then pulled the commits from the remote. Having taken care that no conflicts were present, it resulted in a merge commit, as I expected but was not 100% sure of.

Comment: If you don't like merge commits (like me), try `git pull --rebase` next time :)

Comment: god I guess i have to face it...;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the gitflow appropriately?
If you are you can just merge back your master branch to your feature branch

```
git checkout featurebranch
git merge origin master
```